# Image file uploaded to server is corrupted/format not supported; python, cgi and html

Tags: python-2.7, cgi, server-side-scripting

I have code that is to upload an image file from the user's system, but on the server side, the uploaded image is not displayed and when I try to open manually, it says file format not supported
Here is the html code

```
  <html>
<head>
    <title>DICON Employee Form</title>
</head>

<body>
<form enctype = "multipart/form-data" method = "post" action = "http://localhost/cgi-bin/DICON_FORM.py">
<p>File: <input type = "file" name = "filename" /></p>
<input type = "submit" value = "Upload" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the cgi-python script

```
#!c:\Python27\python.exe

import cgi
import cgitb
import os
import MySQLdb

cgitb.enable()
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

if not form.has_key("EmployeeID"):
    print "Location: /DICON_FORM.html\n"
else:
    print """Content-type: text/html

    <head><title>FORM</title></head>
    <body>"""

    employeeID = form["EmployeeID"].value
    firstName = form["FirstName"].value
    lastName = form["LastName"].value
    others = form["Others"].value

    fileitem = form["filename"]
    fn = ""

    if fileitem.filename:
        fn = os.path.basename(fileitem.filename)
        open(fn, 'wb').write(fileitem.file.read()) 
    print "</body></html>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to change the first line in the python script to
    #!c:\Python27\python.exe - u
    This opens the compiler in binary mode and images can then be written correctly